# Java Thread: explain why not always print the newest value of variable

Tags: java, multithreading

I have this piece of code using Java Thread:

```
public class ThreadExample implements Runnable{

    public Thread thread;
    static int i = 0;
    ThreadExample(){
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThreadExample example = new ThreadExample();
        for(int n =0; n<1000; n++){
            System.out.println("main thread "+i);
            i++;
        }
    }

    public void run(){
        for(int index=0; index<1000; index++){
            System.out.println("Sub thread "+i);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

And when run, the result is:

```
main thread 0
Sub thread 0
Sub thread 2
Sub thread 3
Sub thread 4
Sub thread 5
Sub thread 6
Sub thread 7
Sub thread 8
Sub thread 9
Sub thread 10
Sub thread 11
Sub thread 12
main thread 1
....
```

I know thread that run don't follow by its order. But, the thing that I don't understand is: why main thread prints 1 (it prints variable i), when variable i has come to 12 ? (because subthread has printed to 12).

Thanks :)

Comment: @fge i have used volatile, but the problem still here :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely, the explanation is that there's a large delay between when the text is prepared to be printed and when it can actually be printed. The main thread prepared the statement "main thread 1" and then had to wait until the sub thread released the lock on `System.out`, and it acquired the lock, in order to actually print it.

If you make `i` volatile, and it still happens, then this is pretty much the only explanation.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the threads won't see each others modifications without some synchronization or `volatile` keyword.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.4

Answer (score 1):

The result is likely due to the way the lock acquisition (which occurs under the covers for the System.out.println call) isn't inherently fair. Unfair implementations, or at least partially unfair ones, usually don't guarantee that the threads will acquire the lock in the same order they wait for it.

The result is that when two threads are competing for the lock repeatedly in a tight loop (as in your example), you will usually have a run of acquisitions by one threads, then a run of acquisitions by the other, and so on. Unfair locks often are simpler to implement, and generally improve performance (throughput) over the perfectly fair alternative for highly contended locks, since they don't suffer from the [lock convoy](http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/PermaLink,guid,e40c2675-43a3-410f-8f85-616ef7b031aa.aspx) effect. The downside, evidently, is that no guarantees are made about the order particular waiting threads will acquire the lock, and in theory some waiting threads can be starved out in definitely (in practive this may not occur, or the lock may be designed with a fallback to fair behavior when some threads has been waiting an unusual amount of time).

Given unfair locks, the pattern about is natural.  The loop in your 2nd thread got the lock, and shortly after the first thread read 1 and began waiting - the String to output has already been concatenated with the leading text at this point, so the value 1 is "baked in". The main thread has to wait for several lock/unlock pairs on the other thread, at which it gets a chance to run, and prints the old value.

An alternate explanation is that due to the lack of volatile, the interpreter or JIT isn't even reading the shared value of i anymore, but has hosted the variable into a register - this is allowed under the JMM and JVM spec since there are no intervening methods which might modify i.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is because of the buffering of `System.out`

Try to write in a file or call `System.out.flush()` after each printlen.

and try to increase `i` via a synchronized method:

```
public synchronized void increment() {
  i++;
}
```

Comment: I have tried, but the result doesn't change. it prints not by increasing order.

Comment: Tried the unbuffered *System.err* instead?